# Chrome Extension doesn't load my images [Sorta-Fixed]

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a basic chrome extension to inject CSS into a site, and it's all being injected besides my image, bg.png. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS

```
   #docs-editor {
        background-image: url("bg.png"); !important
    }
```

Manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Modify CSS and HTML",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Lateral blog post demo extension",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["g_docs.css"],
    "matches": ["*://docs.google.com/document/d/*"]
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/bg.png",
    "images/*",
    "bg.png"
]
}
```

Thanks, 
I've tryed using the @@extensionID thing and still have yet to get it to work.

Sorta-Fix; By adding webview to the manifest I just linked the images to various webpages instead of storing locally.

Comment: The `!important` should go before the `;`. (`background-image: url('bg.png') !important;`)

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed it on that line. (It didn't change anything though D;) @MichaelLonghurst

Comment: Okay, well I shall investigate and see if I can figure anything out for you. It was worth a try though :)

Comment: I think I've got it. In `"web_accessible_resources"`, it points to `/images/bg.png`, however in your CSS file, you are missing the directory `/images/`. Try changing your CSS line to `background-image: url('/images/bg.png')`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but all those point to the copies of the same image due to all my attempts. I gave it a try though and there is still nothing.

 As a side note, I know the css worked when I tested it live, its just now that I'm trying to make an extension out of it I can't get it to work. @MichaelLonghurst

Comment: @MichaelLonghurst I did it! Sorta, I ended up just adding webview to the manifest and using a url. 
Thanks for your efforts